# Convert column into nested field in destination table on load job in Big Query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am currently running a job to transfer data from one table to another via a query. But I can't seem to find a way convert a column into a nested field containing the column as a child field. For example, I have a column `customer_id: 3` and I would like to convert it to `{"customer": {"id":3}}`. Below is a snippet of my job data.

```
query='select * FROM ['+ BQ_DATASET_ID+'.'+Table_name+'] WHERE user="'+user+'"'
job_data={"projectId": PROJECT_ID,
                    'jobReference': {
                            'projectId': PROJECT_ID,
                            'job_id': str(uuid.uuid4())
                            },
                    'configuration': {
                        'query': {
                                        'query': query,
                                        'priority': 'INTERACTIVE',
                                        'allowLargeResults': True,
                            "destinationTable":{
                                        "projectId": PROJECT_ID,
                                        "datasetId": user,
                                        "tableId": destinationTable,
                                        },
                                        "writeDisposition": "WRITE_APPEND"
                                    },

                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if the "customer" `RECORD` does not exist in the input schema, it is not currently possible to generate that nested `RECORD` field with child fields through a query.  We have features in the works that will allow schema manipulation like this via SQL, but I don't think it's possible to do accomplish this today.

I think your best option today would be an export, transformation to desired format, and re-import of the data to the desired destination table.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using line delimited JSON with nested entries as the import file format when  populating the source table so it can have a `RECORD` entry to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution is to run

```
select customer_id as customer.id ....
```

Comment: Note that this will not work if the input schema does not contain the customer `RECORD` already. It will return a flat field named "customer_id", even with `flattenResults` set to false.